# Pymodbus Server write callback

Tags: python, modbus

i am setting up a ModbusServer with pymodbus.
i read a datalist over Serial port an write it into datastore of the server.
so i can see data f.e. in ModbusPoll

now i want write back datapoints f.e. dp 1, value 10 function 16 on my modbus server

is there any callback or method to catch which address and value hast changed?

Many Thanks

```
class CustomDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):

    def setValues(self, address, value):
     super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)
     print("wrote {} to {}".format(value, address))

    def setValuesInternal(self, address, value):
     ModbusSparseDataBlock.setValues(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)



def updating_writer(context):
 context[0].setValuesInternal(16, 0, valueDataAct) #update Datastore with Serial values

def run_updating_server():
 block  = CustomDataBlock([0]*378)
 store  = ModbusSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block) 

 context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)


 time = 1  #in seconds
 loop = LoopingCall(f=updating_writer, context=(context))
 loop.start(time, now=False)

 StartTcpServer(context, address=('0.0.0.0', 502))   

 if __name__ == "__main__":
 run_updating_server()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by implementing a custom datablock - see the [example in the documentation](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/custom_datablock.html). You can then do whatever you want in `setValues`; the relevant section from the example is:

```py
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# import the modbus libraries we need
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from pymodbus.version import version
from pymodbus.server.asynchronous import StartTcpServer
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSparseDataBlock
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer, ModbusAsciiFramer

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# import the twisted libraries we need
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# configure the service logging
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class CustomDataBlock(ModbusSparseDataBlock):
    def setValues(self, address, value):
     super(CustomDataBlock, self).setValues(address, value)
     print("wrote {} to {}".format(value, address))

    def setValuesInternal(self, address, value):
     ModbusSparseDataBlock.setValues(self, address, value)


def updating_writer(context):
 print("value before update: " + str(context[0].getValues(4, 1, 1)))
 context[0].store['d'].setValuesInternal(2, [251]) #update Datastore with Serial values
 print("value after update: " + str(context[0].getValues(4, 1, 1)))

def run_updating_server():
 block  = CustomDataBlock([0]*378)
 store  = ModbusSlaveContext(di=block, co=block, hr=block, ir=block)

 context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)


 time = 1  #in seconds
 loop = LoopingCall(f=updating_writer, context=(context))
 loop.start(time, now=False)

 StartTcpServer(context, address=('0.0.0.0', 502))

if __name__ == "__main__":
 run_updating_server()
```

Comment: thanks that works... now i have another problem, when i write the datas from the serial interface to the datastore the implemented CustomDataBlock SetValues also is called...

is there any solution to catch where writes the data?

Comment: You have not reallly provided enough information to answer this. My guess would be that you need to write another function that updates the datablock without calling your custom code and use that for updates from within your own code.

Comment: i had updated my question with pseudocode, here you can see in method updating_writer i wrote data from serialPort to the datastore with the funktion "setValue", so the function "setValues" in CustomDataBlock is also called, but this is not what i want. this funktion should just called when i wrote data clientside (for example from ModbusPoll)

Comment: Please see my extended answer.

Comment: i have update my code... now i get this error message 'ModbusSlaveContext' object has no attribute 'setValuesInternal'

Comment: Please update the code in your question (really need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) otherwise any code I post will include guesswork). I assumed that `context[0]` was a `CustomDataBlock` but its not.. Updated answer to clarify somewhat.

Comment: See amended answer showing how to access store via context.

Comment: okay thats perfect! another thing, i updated your code to have a second slave, how can i check in the CustomDataBlock from which slave the SetValue is called?

Comment: See the help for [ModbusServerContext](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/library/datastore/context.html#pymodbus.datastore.context.ModbusServerContext.__getitem__). Sorry - this is now well beyond your original question; I'd suggest asking a new question if you are unable to figure this out. I'm not accepting your edit to my answer because its no longer working code.